# Why do I need to use Context or a Provider with MobX?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to learn how to use MobX with React, and I don't understand why using a Provider or Context is necessary, if the object that holds the state never changes, only its contents.

E.g. I have a store (a simple timer that changes over time) in store.js:

```
import { decorate, observable, action } from 'mobx';
import React from 'react';

class TheTimer {
    currentTick = 0; // In seconds since start

    tick = () => {
        this.currentTick = Math.floor(performance.now() / 1000);
    }
}

decorate(TheTimer, {
    currentTick: observable,
    tick: action
});

// Bare store
export const timerStore = new TheTimer();
// Store as React context
export const TimerStoreContext = React.createContext(timerStore);

// This makes the timer go
setInterval(timerStore.tick, 100);
```

Now there is no problem using the bare store in a component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

import { timerStore } from './store';

configure({ enforceActions: 'observed' });

const App = observer(() => {
    return (
        <p>{timerStore.currentTick}</p>
    );
});

export default App;
```

Using the context also works:

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

import { TimerStoreContext } from './store';

configure({ enforceActions: 'observed' });

const App = observer(() => {
    const timerStore = React.useContext(TimerStoreContext);

    return (
        <p>{timerStore.currentTick}</p>
    );
});

export default App;
```

(I'm using create-react-app plus mobx, mobx-react, that is React 16.9.0 with MobX 5.13.0 and mobx-react 6.1.3)

Note that the store is created once and from then on it always stays the same object.

**Why is Context used by everybody (or older mobx-react Provider based solutions) when using the store directly as a global variable also works?**

Is it only about testability?

Note that I also have JS code that's not React, the application communicates over Websockets with the server and updates from the server will also lead to actions being called; I plan to use the bare store for that as that code lives outside React components.

Answer (score 13):

I was interested in this question some time ago. And answer that I've got from the maintainers is because of the **testability** of the code.

With the code in your example you are basically treating `TheTimer` class as a singleton.

If you really dislike using `React.context` you could also use the [service locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) instead (but basically it's the same thing)

```js
export const ListHolder = observer(function(props) {
  const listStore = serviceLocator.get(STORES.LIST_STORE)
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.wrap}>
        {listStore.lists.map(list => {
          return <List key={list.id} list={list} />
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
})
```

Also take a look at this long but interesting discussion on the MobX repo about exactly this problem.

[suggested best practice for holding onto a store constructed with props](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-lite/issues/74)

Comment: - Can I assume `STORES.LIST_STORE` to be a constant string by it's casing?
- Is the module serviceLocator void of any dependencies on actual stores and do the stores call a setter on serviceLocator?
If both of these questions can be answered with yes, this component is indeed decoupled from the store. Context on the other hand, still maintains a linear dependency relationship with the store because the store needs to be imported where the context is created. That makes both patterns very different from a software architecture standpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Context is primarily used when some data needs to be accessible by many components at different nesting levels. Apply it sparingly because it makes component reuse more difficult.

Provider allows consuming components to subscribe to context changes.

In Mobx we use providers in the top level to pass all store instances to all the child components that are wrapped with Provider eg

```
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";


<Provider {...Stores}>
   <App/>
 </Provider>
```

Now we can access all the store properties inside the child component as props by using the inject Hoc eg

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>app</div>;
  }
}

export default inject("app")(App);
```

You can also inject multiple stores using inject Hoc to access property stored in multiple store

```
inject(stores => ({
 abc: stores.abc,
 bca: stores.bca
}))
```

So it will resolve the problem of importing the store directly inside component which is also not recommended by mobx

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question. My question is *why* is it not recommended by MobX? Note that your Provider / inject way is not the recommended way by mobx-react anymore, they suggest to use Context like I did. But, *why*?

Comment: The thing is that it is a similar concept like making private variable inside any object-oriented programing language so that other classes cannot access and change it directly.